PowerShell macOS datetime gives wrong day
I am using PowerShell 7.4.4 version in macOS-Ventura in a VM.
My problem is with datetime. The below is my code:
$myday = Get-Date

write-host $myday
# 23/05/1403 AP 14:08:29  ???

write-host $myday.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
# 1403-05-23 14:08:29   ???

Could you anyone explain me how to make this right please.
I installed other oversion. 7.4.2, 7.4.4 and powershell Core. But all showed the same result.

It seems your calendar is using Persian calendar (Shamsi - Jalali).
You can set it to

en-US

by the following command:
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

Too keep it using en-US always , $PROFILE using notepad $PROFILE and add the command to the file so when you open a fresh PowerShell, it run the command automatically and update your calendar.

I do appreciate you Nima.  It leads me to another question.  export LANG="en_US.UTF8" will be enough ?.  I tested and it worked as I expected.  But I noticed there are other options like "LANUGES, LC_CTYPE..." . Do I have to set all the variables as well to get correct answers in any hidden operation ?  Thank you.

@user1389406 Yes, setting export LANG="en_US.UTF8" is almost enough. However, for making sure I suggest you to set a few more environment variables:
LANG="en_US.UTF8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF8"
